# Matlab permutations table

Tags: matlab, math, permutation

I was wondering, let's say we have a table with eg 4 columns that has all possible combinations of numbers between 0 and 2. So it would be

```
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     2
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1
     0     0     1     2
     0     0     2     0
     0     0     2     1
     0     0     2     2
     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     1
```

and so on containing 3^4 rows.

Is there a way for me to find the combination in lets say row 56 without having to construct the whole table, as it is impossible to create a table like this for bigger numbers (eg values ranging from 0 to 100 using >1000 columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This -

```
%%// Given data
rownum = 56; %%// Row number to be found out
arr1=[0 1 2]; %%// Numbers used for perms
Nc = 4; %%// Number of columns

N = numel(arr1);%%// Number of array elements for perms

%%// Combination needed
comb1 = arr1(fliplr(ceil(bsxfun(@mod,rownum,power(N,1:Nc))./power(N,0:Nc-1))))
```

Output -

```
comb1 =

     2     0     0     1
```

Comment: This is a good solution, not as small as the one from @luis-mendo but here you can choose the number of columns in the final result.

Comment: Moreover the solution provided by Luis seems to only can go up to base36 and wont do for lets say N=120.

Comment: @green_leaf Yeah I just noticed that limitation with `dec2base`. At least this `bsxfun` approach works right!

Answer (score 3):

Each combination is the base-3 expansion of a number, starting from 0 and ending in 3^4-1. So you can use [`dec2base`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/dec2base.html) to convert from that number to its expansion:

```
N = 3; %// number of digits
M = 4; %// number of columns
n = 56; %// row number: 1, 2, ..., N^M

result = dec2base(n-1,N)-'0';
```

Comment: Great suggestion, my initial approach was with dec2base too but i couldn't make it work correctly. Do you have any suggestions on how to do the opposite? I tried `bi2de(result,N,'left-msb')` but i get _55_ instead of _56_.

Comment: @green_leaf You have to add 1 because the first row is [0 0 ...0], which would correspond to number 0, but you (like Matlab does) start indexing at 1

Answer (score 2):

The rightmost column of row `n` is simply `mod(n, 3)`.
If you then replace `n` with `floor(n./3)` you can retrieve the next rightmost in the same way.
Rinse and repeat to construct the entire row...